# Validate zip archive in a strict fashion

Tags: java, apache-commons-compress

There is a semi-broken zip-archive that could be extracted from but gives a semi-broken file.

Ubuntu Archive Manager extracts from the archive, but gives a warning:

[image]

The following Java code gives no errors at all:

```
 import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
 import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile;

 import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

 ...

 public static boolean isValidZipFile(final File file) {
        if (file.length() == 0) return false;

        try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file)) {
            final Enumeration<ZipArchiveEntry> entries = zipFile.getEntries();

            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

                if (entry.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    final InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);

                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**Dependencies:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

*N.B.* Contents of the archive is a single text file (that's agreed in advance).

**Q.** How to strictly validate zip file so it is considered invalid for such a case?

**P.S.** It's not absolutely necessary to use `apache-commons-compress`, any other library could be employed as well. The ultimate target is validation reliability.

Comment: "It's ok to rewrite the code using another library but apache-commons-compress" does that mean you specifically do not want a solution to include apache-commons-compress or did you mean "... another library than ..."

Comment: @JoSSte Thanks for drawing my attention to it. It's "than")